# C# Regex decimal number split from complex string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match with regex a string format like this:

94.5-97.8

93-95

94/97

55.5/77.9

Using this regex it works:

```
([0-9]{2}[.,]?([0-9]{1})?)(-||/)([0-9]{2}[.,]?([0-9]{1})?)
```

but I get a regex.Groups result like(testing 94.5-97.8)

```
[0] --> 94.5-97.8
[1] --> 94.5
[2] --> 5
[3] --> -
[4] --> 97.8
[5] --> 8
```

What I need to do is (using a regex pattern) to obtain a regex.Groups like this:

```
[0] --> 94.5-97.8
[1] --> 94.5
[2] --> 97.8
```

Is it possibile?

I'm using C# and .Net Core 2.2.

**UPDATE**

If you put a down vote please, add the comment(with your name) of WHY you consider this question not usefull.

Comment: If you want to define a group that is not caputer use a non-caputer group like `(?:content)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Round brackets defines your groups in case of grouping. So getting rid of that would make it works

```
([0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]?)[-,\/]([0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]?)
```